# Does the Apple Watch ensure data integrity?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, healthkit

I'd like to access heart rate data from the Apple Watch. Can I be sure that the data is authentic and really coming from an Apple Watch?

I found that devices can add digital signatures to their data: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/samples/adding_digital_signatures, but I don't know if the Apple Watch supports this. And if it does, I wonder how secure this is? Is there a tamper-resistant storage with the private key on the Apple Watch device?

Comment: Are you looking to get heart data, filter it by Apple Watch only, and only if it's integrity is verifiable?

Comment: @NitinAlabur I'm not sure I fully get the question, but I'm definitely using the Apple Watch for heart rate data (although tips for other devices are always welcome). And I'd like to find out about the data integrity security levels.